# Line bundle from $\mathcal{O}(p)\cong \mathcal{O}(q)$

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface. If $\mathcal{O}(p)\cong \mathcal{O}(q)$. How to see there exists a line bundle $L$ and $s_1,s_2$ two sections of $L$ such that $s_1$ vanishes only at $p$ and $s_2$ vanishes only at $q$ (and with multiplicity one).

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat tautological.

Denote $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}(p)=\mathcal{O}(q)$.

Let's show that $\mathcal{L}$ does the job.

Start with the standard restriction sequence:

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-p) \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}_p \to 0$$ and twist by $\mathcal{O}(p)$ to get $$0 \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(p) \to \mathcal{O}_p \to 0.$$

Taking the cohomology sequence we get $$0 \to H^0 (\mathcal{O}) \xrightarrow{\phi}H^0(\mathcal{O}(p)) \xrightarrow{\psi} H^0 (\mathcal{O}_p)$$ and using that $H^0 (\mathcal{O}) \neq 0$ we get a nonzero section $\phi(1)$ of $\mathcal{O}(p) = \mathcal{L}$ which first of all vanishes at $p$ (since it is in the image of $\phi$ and therefore in the kernel of $\psi$), second it has no poles (since it is a global section of a line bundle) and third must have 1 zero in total since $\deg \mathcal{O}(p) = 1$.

Repeating this construction with $q$ instead of $p$ and using $\mathcal{O}(q) = \mathcal{L}$ will finish the proof.

Comment: Sorry I feel confused, to $f\in H^0(\mathcal{O}(p))$, then $f$ is a meromorphic function on a compact Riemann surface, then deg((f))=0 so it is supposed to have a pole right?

Comment: Also the sections of $H^0(\mathcal{O}(p))$ are meromorphic functions s.t. $(f)+(p)\ge0$, then it might have a pole at $p$

Comment: @Danny, there are no meromorphic sections appearing here as we are taking global sections of line bundle - global sections are defined everywhere on your Riemann surface and therefore cannot have poles. I think you are confusing how to construct $\mathcal{O}(p)$ and how to think about its sections. It is a standard fact that the divisor associated to a section of $\mathcal{O}(p)$ is linearly equivalent to just $p$ itslef.

Comment: Sorry I still confused, isn’t a global section an element of $H^0(O(p))$? If so then by http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2014-15/2term/ma130b/files/AlgCurv-RS-Miranda.pdf p.271 example 1.8, it says exactly what I wrote

Comment: Here I meant $H^0(O(p))=O(p)(X)$

Comment: By this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172410/a-global-section-of-a-line-bundle-may-have-a-pole?noredirect=1#comment6531496_3172410. It seems your claim about global section is not correct

Comment: @Danny, no you are supposed to think of the divisor of poles and zeros of a section of a line bundle by trivializing the bundle and looking at the divisor of zeros and poles of the function in $\mathcal{O}$ corresponding to the section in the trivialization. You need to carefully parse out all the definitions.